# Querying the Google Domain Shared Contacts API via service account

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm writing an application in C# that aims to query the Google Domain Shared Contacts API to retrieve (and eventually update/add/delete) all domain shared contact records. As this is not currently supported via the .NET client libraries, I have written a procedure to retrieve an oauth 2.0 token to include in my request to https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/example.com/full. I believe I have the oauth 2.0 token request procedure correct, but I am getting a 403 Forbidden error when calling the above mentioned URL with that token. However, if I go into the OAuth 2.0 playground and create a token through there and use that token instead in my C# app, the call succeeds and I get contact records returned.

My question is - does the Domain Shared Contacts API support being called with the credentials of a service account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to include the email address of the "overarching" domain administrator account as the user being managed ('sub' property of claimset when creating Jason Web Token or 'User' property of ServiceAccountCredential initialization). As the domain administrator has access to all domain data, the call to retrieve all domain shared contacts now succeeds.